# No muestra datos GET angular

Tags: angular

Estoy intentado realizar un metodo GET lo cual obtiene la informacion del usuario logueado , lo que quiero realizar es una pantalla donde va a mostrar la informacion del usuario . El metodo Get sale 200 funcionando y trae los datos desde el console pero al momento de pasarlo por el html no muestra los datos

home.html

```
<div class="card m-5" style="width: 18erm" *ngIf="UsuarioLoguedo">
<ul class="list-group">

    <li class="list-group-item"> <strong>usuario : </strong> {{UsuarioLoguedo.usuario}}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item"> <strong>cargo : </strong> {{UsuarioLoguedo.cargo}}</li>

</ul>
```

home.componente

```
export class Page1Component implements OnInit {

 UsuarioLoguedo : any ; 
  constructor(private router: Router , private service : UserService) { }

 ngOnInit() {
  this.service.getuser().subscribe(
   res => {
       this.UsuarioLoguedo = res ; 
   },
   err => {
     console.log(err);
    },
  );
  }

}
```

Usuario.Service

```
   getuser() : Observable<any> {
var  token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Token')); 
let header = new HttpHeaders()
    .set('Accept' , 'application/json')
    .set('Token' , token.token);
 return this.http.get(this.rootUrl + '/usuario', {headers : header}).pipe(map( data =>{
  console.log("Token", data);
  return data;
  }) );;
```

}

Comment: ¿Podrías por favor colocar un console.log para la "res" antes de asignarlo a this.UsuarioLoguedo? y mostrarme que respuesta te da.
tambien colocale a la creacion de la variable UsuarioLoguedo lo siguiente:
UsuarioLoguedo: any;

Comment: Mmmm...veo que el método getuser en el servicio no especifica el tipo de retorno. Deberías definirlo como getuser(): Observable<any>

Comment: https://ibb.co/C1m1nBn
Asi me dio el resultado  Voy a editar el codigo

Answer (score 2):

```
/* Que conste que no me deja añadir comentarios, no tengo reputación suficiente, que después me critican.*/
```

Pero podrías poner
e importar map.

```
getuser() {
var tokenHeader = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':  'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Basic' + btoa(localStorage.getItem('Token'))});
 return this.http.get(this.rootUrl + '/usuario', {headers : tokenHeader}).pipe(map( data =>{
console.log("desde el servicio", data);
return data;
}) );
}
```

Y ver en navegador en red si muestra algún resultado cuando ejecuta esa dirección. 
Un saludo.

Comment: bro me salio el resultado del console log con el usuario ahora que procedo hacer

Comment: Si puedes mostrar la respuesta en consola, mas o menos te podríamos guiar, un poco. ejemplo `data:[user:[name:'el nombre', id: '4'] ]`, por poner un ejemplo así podrías saber que variables tienes y puedes acceder. Un saludo,